# Mapping and linking model instances in a Rails show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, dictionary, interpolation

I have a scenario where an album has many tracks and the tracks have the possibility to have featured artists, also know as `artists`. The associations are setup just fine but its mainly my view code that suffers from major verbosity:

```
<table>
  <% @album.tracks.each do |track| %>
    <td>
      <%= raw !track.artists.empty? ? "#{track.name} (feat. #{track.artists.map {|artist| link_to artist.name, artist_path(artist)}.to_sentence({:two_words_connector => ' & ', :last_word_connector => ' & '})})" : track.name %>
   </td>
<table>
```

The objective for the above is to display the name of the track and if the track has any featured artists (with the help of the `to_sentence` helper method), list them out and link to their own `show` view. A rendered example would look something like this:

```
Give It To Me (feat. Justin Timberlake & Nelly Furtado)
```

or if there's more than two featured artists:

```
Good Friday (feat. Common, Pusha T, Kid Cudi, Big Sean & Charlie Wilson)
```

Is there any way I could accomplish the following  without writing such a long expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move all that logic into a helper, for example create a method `application_helper.rb`:

```
def display_track(track)
  if track.artists.empty? 
    track.name
  else
    links = track.artists.map {|artist| link_to artist.name, artist_path(artist) }
    sentence = links.to_sentence(two_words_connector: ' & ', last_word_connector: ' & ')

    "#{track.name} (feat. #{sentence})"    
  end
end
```

Then your view simplifies to:

```
<table>
  <% @album.tracks.each do |track| %>
    <td>
      <%= raw display_track(track) %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just remove `do` from the `map` code block and I'll mark this as correct. Otherwise you'd encounter an error.